# Error when using RColorBrewer to plot

Tags: r, r-raster, rgdal

I am trying to make a plot of a map from raster data.  I am using this code:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(classInt)
library(RColorBrewer)

NDII = raster("G:\\Sheyenne\\image_differencing\\NDII\\differenced.tif")
value.vector = values(NDII)
breaks.qt = classIntervals(value.vector, n = 6, style = "jenks", intervalClosure = "right")
print (plot(NDII, breaks=breaks.qt$brks, col = brewer.pal(6, "Set1")))
```

but this returns:

`Error in print(plot(NDII, breaks = breaks.qt$brks, col = brewer.pal(6,  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'print': Error in .asRaster(x, col, breaks, zrange, colNA, alpha = alpha) : 
  could not find function "brewer.pal"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You provide no reproducible example, and I can't reproduce your error.
The following code, which is the same as yours using the reproducible example of the R logo as a raster (and with the shortcut of using `NDII[]` instead of storing `values(NDII)` in a variable) works just fine for me...

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(classInt)
library(RColorBrewer)

NDII = raster(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
# next line is really slow, I'd advise to run crop(NDII, extent(0,20,0,20)) 
# before to make quick tests
breaks.qt = classIntervals(NDII[], n = 6, style = "jenks", 
                           intervalClosure = "right")
plot(NDII, breaks=breaks.qt$brks, col = brewer.pal(6, "Set1"))
```

Do you reproduce your error with this code? Maybe you can start with a new, fresh session?

[image]

Comment: You might want to clarify the difference between your code and the OP's, to make it a more complete answer...

Comment: Well, there is no difference actually... which I now mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Your example is reproducible for me.  Still not sure why my code won't work, new sessions doesn't fix it but it is apparently something on my end then.

Comment: I faced the same problem but the error disappeared when I run library(RColorBrewer).  Apparently, you first have to run RColorBrewer.